# How can we extract pointer type in LLVM

Tags: c, llvm

I have the following LLVM IR

```
%6 = load i32** %imw, align 8
%arrayidx = getelementptr inbounds i32* %6, i64 10
```

I want to extract `i32` from these instructions in my LLVM pass. Can anyone guide me on how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

First you access an operand you are interested in with `instruction->getOperand(i)` and then call `->getType()` on it. The `llvm::Type` class has a lot of helper classes and `->isPointerTy()` is what you are probably interested in.

Comment: ``isPointerTy()`` returns a ``bool``. I am interested in ``i32``.

Comment: Then there is `isIntegerTy()`. If you want to extract `i32` from `i32*`, use `getPointerElementType()`.

Comment: or you can use non-deprecated `getNonOpaquePointerElementType()` with previous check, that type is `isPointerTy()` and **NOT** `isOpaquePointerTy()`